# How to remove the 1 last character on every line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex, characters

In Notepad++, how do I turn this:

```
aliraft
```

into this:

```
aliraf
```

Comment: Should be trivial with regular expression search and replace. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have big list and like do that    

Find What: ^.?(.*)

Replace with: \1

Search Mode Regular expression

that remove first character but i need remove last character

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Notepad++ specifically?

Answer (score 4):

Here

```
^(.*).$
```

This means

```
^ start from the beginning of the line
(.*) get as many any characters, put in \1
. one more character
$ end of the line
```

Because we need "one more character", the first grab can't get everything, so is left with the whole line except one character.  Then we replace with `\1`.

You could also simply replace `.$` with nothing

Comment: You could also simply replace `.$` with nothing.

Comment: @Bob - not sure why you didn't just enhance the answer, so I did it for you.

Comment: The ".$" will also match the "form feed" character 0x0C as end of line and will delete a character before it. How to avoid that?

Comment: @Eiver The OP *wants* to delete the character before the end of line.  What do you want to do?  If this deleted an `\f` that you wanted to replace, then use `\1\f` in the replace statement.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to do this with a macro as well.

Macro->Start Recording

"End" key->"Back(space)" key->"Down Arrow" key->"Home" key

Macro->Stop Recording

Macro->Run Macro Multiple Times.